# Deserializing XML with empty array returns an array with a single object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

When deserializing an XML containing an empty array I expect this array to be null. Instead, I get an array with a single object with all properties set to null.

Classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "thing")]
public class Thing
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<thing>
  <items/>
</thing>
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
public void DeserializeTest()
{
    var xml = ""; // XML here

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Thing));

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var thing = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Thing;

        thing.Items.Should().BeNull(); // fails
    }
}
```

What I get:
[image]

I must be missing something?

Comment: I am thinking about it and I have a question: What would be inside items if it wasn't empty?

Comment: @Adam <item><name>Bob</name></item> - something like that

Comment: Just to note - deserialized object contains an empty array, which is actually preferable to it being null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `XmlArray` attribute to define your array. This declaration should work:

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "thing")]
public class Thing
{
    [XmlArray("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe is the problem: You are mapping the tag `<Items>` (with a s) to a object with an property called Items (with a s) of the type array of Item (without a s) that is mapped to the tag `<Item>` (without a s), and this is causing a confusion.

It does make sense that there is a Item there because you do have an `<Items/>` tag in your XML. And it does make sense that this Item is null because there is nothing inside the tag `<Items/>`

I think a XML with items in it would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<thing>
  <items>
    <item name="some name"/>
  </items>
</thing>
```

In this case your Items would be a one item list with an item object. Do understand what I mean?
Try running your code with more than one `<Items>` tag or without any and you will see the result.